# How to send string from client to server via POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to send a string from the front- to the backend of my node js application.

on the serverside my code looks like this:

```
app.post('/mydb/post', function(req, res, next) {

console.log(req.body);

});
```

The string should be sent via this:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = '/mydb/post';
var params = 'john';
http.open('POST', url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');

http.onload = function () {
  // do something to response
  console.log(this.responseText);
};
http.send(params);
```

But the body of the request seems to be empty..

Maybe you know something, that would help.

Kind regards,
mg

Comment: try setting the `Content-Type` header value to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I did that first, and then tried text, but same result

Comment: if you are using `expressjs` use https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Answer (score 0):

You have to change contentType. 
use this.

https://gist.github.com/seunggabi/6aa43dbcf4d5238d940f7b0b49fee989

```js
function requestUtils(method, url, body) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            console.log(this);
            console.log(url, body);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(body); 
}

requestUtils('post', '/mydb/post', 'name=john')
```